# Block new posts and emails from closed tickets

Tags: case

I cant change fields. BUT, I can still post things in a closes Ticket and send Emails FROM a closed Ticket.
How to stop this.

Comment: Make a new record type so you can make a new page layout without those things?

Comment: If you're using dynamic form feature, You can hide the Chatter component based on Status value (**like closed status**, `Chatter component visibility = false`)

Comment: But for "Send Email" Quick action. You can't hide in `Dynamic form` feature. But you can add "Rich Text" component above `Related List`, In there you can provide the information like `Please avoid to send emails from Closed cases`. So that user's will get to know.

Comment: I need to review old posts / comments / emails. If i disable using dynamic form I can't review older files.

Answer (score -1):

Need to write trigger on Task,Event, Email Message and Post.
Modify the code as per requirement to Post, EmailMessage, Task, Event.

```
trigger manageClosdcasesTask on Task (before insert) {

// Go through the new or updated tasks and check if they are related to a closed case

    for (Task thisTask : Trigger.new) {


        // Get the related case ID from the WhatId field

        Id caseId = thisTask.WhatId;

        // Check if the case ID is valid and not null
       
 if (caseId != null && caseId.getSObjectType() == Case.getSObjectType()) {


            // Query the case status from the database
            

String caseStatus = [SELECT Status FROM Case WHERE Id = :caseId].Status;

            // Check if the case status is closed
            
if (caseStatus == 'Closed') {
               
 // Throw an exception and block the action
                

thisTask.addError('You cannot create or edit tasks for a closed case.');
            }

        }

    }

}
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).